# ruby whitespace

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

are there different sensitivities/settings to whitespace in ruby?

i have a RoR project, where an active record call has a lot of components:

```
    max_stuff = FooSummary.select("max(stuff) as stuff")
                        .joins(:foo => :bar)
                        .where("user_id = ? and record_date < ?", r.user_id, r.record_date)
                        .group("user_id")
                        .first
```

1.9.3 works fine with this on my mac, but on the ubuntu server it runs on, it complains about the fact that .joins is on a separate line (unexpected . expecting kEND)

what gives?

Comment: tried both 1.8 and 1.9.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the period to the preceding line. If parsing line-by-line,

```
foo = bar
```

looks like a full statement, and the next line, taken separately, is a syntax error:

```
.baz
```

However, this can't be a statement:

```
foo = bar.
```

and the parser knows it has to append the next line as well:

```
baz
```

(which gives the same parse as `foo = bar.baz`, as expected).

Comment: @muistooshort: Yes, indeed. Already covered, and very well, by Stefan. I gave an upvote and everything.

Answer (score 8):

This syntax was [introduced](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_1_0/NEWS) in Ruby 1.9.1:

> ### Language core changes
>
> - New syntax and semantics
>
>   - …
>   - Newlines allowed before ternary colon operator (:) and method call dot operator (.)

Most likely your server is running an older Ruby version, i.e. 1.9.0 or 1.8.x.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
max_stuff = FooSummary.select("max(stuff) as stuff") \
                    .joins(:foo => :bar) \
                    .where("user_id = ? and record_date < ?", r.user_id, r.record_date) \
                    .group("user_id") \
                    .first
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try various combinations of the following, where either `(` ends the line, or `)` begins the line. Here I am showing both, and you can adjust to your liking.

```
max_stuff = FooSummary.select(
                              "max(stuff) as stuff"
                     ).joins(
                             :foo => :bar
                     ).where(
                             "user_id = ? and record_date < ?", r.user_id, r.record_date
                     ).group(
                             "user_id"
                     ).first
```

Answer (score 0):

Put dottes on the end of lines

```
max_stuff = FooSummary.select("max(stuff) as stuff").
                       joins(:foo => :bar).
                       where("user_id = ? and record_date < ?", r.user_id, r.record_date).
                       group("user_id").
                       first
```